# Distribute load via normal distribution over 24 hours with the peak at noon?

Tags: javascript, math, normal-distribution

I'm trying to unevenly distribute a load over each hour of a day with peak handling around noon when more people are available. Basically, I want a "Normal Distribution" of tasks as apposed to a simple `n / 24 = hourly load`.

The goal is that most of the work needs to be handed out during the middle of the day with less work early in the morning and late at night.

[image: Normal Distribution Chart]

This is as far as I've gotten producing something of a curve.

```
// Number per day
const numberPerDay = 600;
const numberPerHour = numberPerDay / 24;

let total = 0;
for (let hour = 1; hour < 24; hour++) {
  // Normal Distribution should be higher at 12pm / noon
  // This Inverse bell-curve is higher at 1am and 11pm
  const max = Math.min(24 - hour, hour);
  const min = Math.max(hour, 24 - hour);
  const penalty = Math.max(1, Math.abs(max - min));

  const percentage = Math.floor(100 * ((penalty - 1) / (24 - 1)));
  const number = Math.floor(numberPerHour - (numberPerHour * percentage / 100));

  console.log(`hour: ${hour}, penalty: ${penalty}, number: ${number}`);
  total += number;
}

console.log('Expected for today:', numberPerDay);
console.log('Actual for today:', total);
```

Live [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Xeoncross/8thwmfj7/1/).

Which produces something like this:

[image: demo chart]

Comment: For a normal distribution you need a variance and exception of then distribution in formula. Do you mean a real meaning of mathematical `normal distribution` or you are trying to find something similar to fit the curve above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a Gaussian function. The following link might be helpful: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236727/the-x-y-coordinates-for-points-on-a-bell-curve-normal-distribution

You would need to choose your mean and standard deviation (sigma). Here is a snippet I found:

```
//taken from Jason Davies science library
// https://github.com/jasondavies/science.js/
function gaussian(x) {
    var gaussianConstant = 1 / Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI),
    mean = 0,
    sigma = 1;
    x = (x - mean) / sigma;
    return gaussianConstant * Math.exp(-.5 * x * x) / sigma;
};
```

https://gist.github.com/phil-pedruco/88cb8a51cdce45f13c7e

To get it to do 0-24 you set the mean to 12 and adjust the sigma to spread the curve out as much as you need. You'll also want to scale the "y" value a little bit.

### Update

I have created a JS Fiddle for you that plots what I think you need.
https://jsfiddle.net/arwmxc69/2/

```
var data = [];
var scaleFactor = 600
        mean = 12,
        sigma = 4;

function gaussian(x) {
    var gaussianConstant = 1 / Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI);
    x = (x - mean) / sigma;
    return gaussianConstant * Math.exp(-.5 * x * x) / sigma;
};

for(x=0;x<24;x+=1) {
    var y = gaussian(x)
    data.push({x:x,y:y*scaleFactor});
}
```

Comment: A Gaussian function is probably a viable approach, but I am not sure what that would look like for a 1-24 (hour) range.

Comment: I have added some more to the answer and added a JSFiddle.

Comment: Any chance you can mark this as the best answer, as its a working solution, or let me know if you need me to add anything?

Comment: Thank you. Stackoverflow has a minimum time limit for some things (like accepting an answer or awarding a bounty).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are okay with an approximation. In that case, something like y=sin(pi*x)^4 could be a relatively good (and easy) solution. One may then make this distribution wider or slimmer by raising y to some power close to 1.

[image: y = sin(pi * x) from 0 to 1]

Also, it's cyclic, so that helps implementaion by doing something like

```
y = (sin(pi*hour/24))^4
```

and scaling to fit the 600 jobs.